# How to Get spid using flyway tool?

Tags: sql-server, flyway, sqlcmd

I am using a flyway tool to run SQL script. I have requirements where I need to return the SPID during the run time in the flyway. Are there any config parameters or variables which can return SPID?

Comment: [@@SPID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/spid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Return it to where?

Comment: Return in flyway logs .

Comment: Why do you have a requirement to return a SPID to the logs?